# Cloud vision API for text detection

Tags: android

How I can use the cloud vision API for text detection. I have no idea that how can I use it in my project. Provide me any link that will help me that how can I use it in my project

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the google cloud vision
Refer this [link(google cloud vision docs)](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) you will get more information

This is [link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) is helpful for verifying output in web interface